# Shopping basket rule doesn't work when there's more then 5 items in the basket - Magento

Tags: magento, cart, rule

I have set up a discount for certain users to get a 20% discount on all products. However when they add more than 5 items the rules stops working for any items over 5. I haven't set any conditions to limit it to 5 items so I can't work out why this is happening.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: do you have any other `shopping cart price rule` , if so check the priority of that rule..... you need to give higher priority for this rule to work..... also try changing price to 1 for 6 products and add those to cart......

Answer (score 1):

check the configuration may be you have max quantity to 5 !
[image]